# duplicate/mirror touch events from uiview to uiscrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview, uiscrollview

i have a uiwebview and an uiview next to each other everone taking 50% of the screen width.

i can smoothly scroll the uiwebview - and i want to be able that if i scroll up/down on the uiview - that the uiwebview scrolls in the given direction.

already subclassed uiview - and trie'd to send the touchesEnded... events to the webview.scrollview.

.h

```
@interface UIViewScrollDispatcher : UIView
@property(nonatomic, assign) id scroller;
```

.m

```
@implementation UIViewScrollDispatcher

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   [self.scroller touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   [self.scroller touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
} 

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        [self.scroller touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ 
    NSLog(@"TOUCHHHH %@", self.scroller);
    [self.scroller touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

}
```

using it like this:

```
UIViewScrollDispatcher * rightarea = [[UIViewScrollDispatcher alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
rightarea.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
rightarea.scroller=self.webView.scrollView;
```

tried it with `self.webView` and `self.webView.scrollView` 
doesn't work  - any help?

btw: the NSLog inside the touchesMoved gets called

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok - did it with uiscrollview subclass and sync the .contentOffset and .contentSize